# Read Data from S3 into Spark data frame using Scala

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to read data from "s3://fakePath/subFakePath/sub-sub-FakePath/*.gz" into spark running on my local.
I am specifying fs.s3a.access.key" and "fs.s3a.secret.key" in my scala code using

```
SqlContext.read()
```

I also have the hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar in my classpath.
The error I get is

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem:
>   Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be
>   instantiated

I have gone through  the answers on StackOverflow regarding this problem but that doesn't seem to solve my problem.
I'd greatly appreciate if someone can point me to the piece I am missing , or not getting here.

Comment: Code I am using is:
val inputDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3a://fakepath/files/*.gz")
I am getting the error on the ".load()" function.

Comment: Where and why are you using SQLContext? You should specify the Amazon keys in the SparkSession, not there

Comment: I did use SparkSession according to this: https://gist.github.com/claudinei-daitx/3766d01b070f3f0f8d1b64fd06b71585
Still getting an error.
Short Error log...
WARN FileSystem: Cannot load filesystem
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/event/ProgressListener

Answer (score 0):

If you use Amazon EMR services you will not run into this problem, since all jars will get added to the paths appropriately.

If s3a, s3n, s3 filesystem could not be instantiated, then it is due to the aws-sdk jars are not in the path.

Averal several hours of investigation here is how it worked for me,

> ./spark-shell  --master yarn-client --jars
>   /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/hadoop-auth.jar,/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/hadoop/aws-java-sdk-1.10.65.jar
>   --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m

Hope it helps.